# Poco::Net::FTPClientSession hangs for 129 seconds on open() method , if the ftp host does not exist

Tags: c++, ftp, poco-libraries

I am using poco libraries to access ftp server, on yocto linux (hw is a microcontroller).
If I specify a valid address (ftp host) all works properly, if I use a non-existing ftp address , the "open" method hangs for 129 seconds! Afterward it throws the following Poco::Exception..

```
displayText->"N4Poco9ExceptionE"
what->"Exception"
message->""
name->"Exception"
code->"110"
```

here the code..

```
Poco::Net::FTPClientSession ftp;
try
{
    ftp.open(host,port);     <<<<<<<<<  hangs here   
    ftp.login(userName,password);
    ftp.logout();
    ftp.close();
}
catch(Poco::Exception exc)
{
}
```

The setTimeout() methods works only after calling the open() method (otherwise it throws an exception). However ,if I set the internal _timeout variable with a c++ pointer hack, no luck..seems not related to ftp timeout.

If I break the debugger this is the stack..

```
1 __libc_connect connect.c 26 0xffffbe68bb8c 
2 ??                          0xffffbf1b1ab0 
3 ??
```

(connect.c)

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sysdep-cancel.h>
#include <socketcall.h>

int    __libc_connect (int fd, __CONST_SOCKADDR_ARG addr, socklen_t len)
{
#ifdef __ASSUME_CONNECT_SYSCALL
  return SYSCALL_CANCEL (connect, fd, addr.__sockaddr__, len);    <<< THE DEBUGGER BREAKS HERE
#else
  return SOCKETCALL_CANCEL (connect, fd, addr.__sockaddr__, len);
#endif
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.
Best regards,

Alex

Comment: So it times out waiting for the DNS query, what were you expecting...?

Comment: @HongOoi TImes out waiting for the SYN-ACK response. The DNS timeout is only a few seconds, not two minutes.

Comment: See if you can set a *connect* timeout. The timeout method you tried is for a read timeout.

Comment: Hi Ooi, thanks for your answer. The problem is that Poco::Net::FTPClientSession does not allow to set a timeout (to reduce the two minutes).. For example the wget command by default waits two minutes, but using -T parameter I can reduce the timeout..for example 10 seconds (that is reasonable for the human interface)

Comment: @ Marquis of Lorne , (thanks for your answers!) the Poco::Net::FTPClientSession have only one timeout setter, it work only once the connection is enstablished (after the open())..otherwise it throws an exception. Do you mean to call some linux low-level function?

Answer (score 0):

If nobody know how to solve using poco FTPClientSession object, I can try to precede the FTPClientSession::open() by this call (QT lib)..

```
QTcpSocket socket;
socket.connectToHost("xxx.xxx.xxx.198",21);
bool bConnected = socket.waitForConnected(10*1000); //ms
```